# What happens behind tf.sqrt() call?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sqrt

I am trying to understand what happens behind tf.sqrt() call (I mean the call-stack). I got to know that gen_math_ops.py is generated during TF compilation which has a sqrt function in it. But it seems that sqrt in implemented in two places,

1. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.9/tensorflow/core/ops/math_ops.cc
2. https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.9/tensorflow/core/kernels/cwise_op_sqrt.cc

Can anyone please let me know how these are connected and how sqrt is executed behind the scenes?

Thank you!